# Producing a print layout using 2nd map view in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am trying to produce a map like this completely in QGIS:

[image]

I can generate each half of the map in the main program by using `View->New Map View` but I can't then find a way to make a map in the print composer refer to my 2nd map view (Map 1).

[image]

I thought maybe I could just change the map projection in the 2nd map on the composer but then it remains blank (may just need a method for setting the extent?).

I've also seen reference to using map themes and follow map theme but I don't seem to be able to create more than one map theme at a time so that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: The additional map view feature is not used very commonly, I think. If it's not possible to link a print layout map to a second map view, that seems like an oversight. Perhaps you should make a feature request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this can be done without the second data-frame. If i understand your question correctly, i would just add as many map frames to the print composer as you need, pan and zoom them in place and lock them when they are ok.
All with just one set of themes in one map view...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

After some more experimentation, it can be done **but** the trick is to not use either of the polar projections for the map canvas. Instead leave the main map in epsg:4326 and then in the two maps in the print composer set EPSG:3413 and EPSG:3986 and all will be well.

[image]